# Unexpected behaviors with closure function scope

Tags: javascript, for-loop, closures

I am fairly certain this is a ten penny closure question.  But having read a few articles on closures, I still cannot get this to work.

`character` is always returned as 'Z'.  `character` is also a global variable.

I need "render" to remember the character in the loop:

```
populateList: function()
{           
    var render = function(tx, result)
    {   
        console.log(character);

        for (var i = 0; i < result.rows.length; i++) 
        {
            var contact = result.rows.item(i);
            console.log(contact.Name);
        }
    }

    var str = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
    for(var i = 0; i < str.length; i++)
    {
        var nextChar = str.charAt(i);
        database.open();
        var sql = "SELECT Name FROM Contact WHERE Name LIKE \'" + nextChar + "%\' ORDER BY Name";
        database.query(sql, render);
    }
}
```

Comment: so what exactly is the problem?

Comment: Right off the bat - raw sql strings in javascript is BEGGING for trouble.

Comment: and `character` is defined where exactly? looks like a global variable, which can be the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var render = function(character)
{
    return function(tx, result)
    {
        console.log(character);

        for (var i = 0; i < result.rows.length; i++) 
        {
            var contact = result.rows.item(i);
            console.log(contact.Name);
        }
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
database.query(sql, render(nextChar));
```

**Edit:**

Also, asawyer is correct in his comment above -- assuming you are using [node-mysql](https://github.com/felixge/node-mysql), it has support for parameterized queries:

```
database.query("SELECT * FROM foo WHERE bar = ?", [ 1 ]);
```

Use that and save yourself some trouble!

Answer (score 0):

Untested:

```
populateList: function()
{           
    var render = function(char)
    {   
        console.log(char);
        return function(tx, result) {

            for (var i = 0; i < result.rows.length; i++) 
            {
                var contact = result.rows.item(i);
                console.log(contact.Name);
            }
        };
    }

    var str = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
    for(var i = 0; i < str.length; i++)
    {
        var nextChar = str.charAt(i);
        database.open();
        var sql = "SELECT Name FROM Contact WHERE Name LIKE \'" + nextChar + "%\' ORDER BY Name";
        database.query(sql, render(nextChar));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use an immediately executing function that returns a function that calls `render` with the parameters:

```
database.query(sql, (function(nextChar) {
    return function(tx, result) {
        return render(tx, result, nextChar);
    };
})(nextChar));
```

Then add the appropriate `nextChar` parameter to `render`, too.

Answer (score 0):

```
var render = function(tx, result)
{   
    console.log(character);
    ***var char = character;***
    for (var i = 0; i < result.rows.length; i++) 
    {
        var contact = result.rows.item(i);
        ***console.log(char);***
        console.log(contact.Name);
    }
}
```

i guess this is what you need. add the highlighted lines. cheers